# fetching just one row from a type

Tags: sql, db2, distinct

I have one table **ticket** and other table **log**. There are many logs for each row in **ticket**. I want to know if certain string is in some log and then fetch one register from **ticket** it doesn't matter which one, because I just want to get one row per **ticket**. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT ticket.id,ticket.description,ticket.owner 
FROM ticket
JOIN log
ON (log.ticketid=ticket.id)
where log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Select top 1 ticket.id, tick..... 
or Limit 1, 
or fetch first row only
What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is this "I want one row" or is this "I want one row per ticket id"?

Comment: Edited. I just want to check for the existence of at least one record in log that contains the specified string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ticket
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM log
           WHERE log.ticketid = ticket.id
             AND log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  ticket.id, ticket.description, ticket.owner 
FROM
  ticket
INNER JOIN
  log
    ON (log.ticketid=ticket.id)
WHERE
  log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'
GROUP BY
  ticket.id, ticket.description, ticket.owner
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the SQL Limit option?

```
SELECT ticket.id,ticket.description,ticket.owner 
FROM ticket
JOIN log
ON (log.ticketid=ticket.id)
where log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I tried it on DB2 unsuccessfully, it doesn't recognize LIMIT as a keyword.

Comment: Yeah, you didn't mention it was DB2 in the OP, so I assumed it was MySQL. What about



down vote
You could try using the SQL Limit option?

`SELECT ticket.id,ticket.description,ticket.owner 
FROM ticket
JOIN log
ON (log.ticketid=ticket.id)
where log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'
fetch first 1 rows only;`

Comment: it doesn't work, either.. I need just one row ocurrence from ticket if there exists one related log row that contains the specified string. Thanks.

Comment: Does it return an error? That is the correct syntax to limit it to one row.

Comment: A quick search on here suggests you could also do

`SELECT 1
FROM ticket
JOIN log
ON (log.ticketid=ticket.id)
where log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'`

Answer (score 0):

The usual DB2 equivalent to LIMIT 1 is FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY:

```
SELECT ticket.id,ticket.description,ticket.owner 
FROM ticket
JOIN log
ON (log.ticketid=ticket.id)
where log.description LIKE '%someparameter%'
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

You can also enable the LIMIT syntax via:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=4000
```

Or:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
```